# Add Span Between Currency Symbol and Price in Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

I am looking to split the price from the currency symbol so i can add

```
<span class="price" itemprop="price">
```

Between the two.

I have found the code in the price.

```
<p class="special-price">
    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
    <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?> 
    </span>
</p>
```

How do i go about changing this so i can place the span between the symbol and price.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get price without currency

```
$_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, false, false)
```

To get current currency symbol

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol()
```

So your code would become something like this:

```
<p class="special-price">
   ...
   <span class="currency-code"> <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?> </span>
   <span class="price" itemprop="price"> <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, false, false); ?> </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @William it worked exactly how i need it too.

Comment: I have discovered that the price has 3 decimal place afterwards how would i reduce this to 2 decimal places it also is not showing the 0 at the end of the price too

Comment: that's weird because it's default to 2 decimal place. However you can use $_coreHelper->roundPrice($price) to convert it back to 2 decimal place.

Comment: Using $_coreHelper->roundPrice($price) returns a fatal error.

Comment: hi Ryan have you tried 
$_coreHelper->roundPrice($_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, false, false)) ?